# regex - How do I exclude "%" and "_"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im allowing numbers, letters, and special characters except for `%` and `_` in my html textbox. I have the pattern `/[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$^&*()-+=]/`. I think its not the best way to do it because I have to list all special characters except the two mentioned. Is there a way in which I don't have to list all special characters and don't include the two mentioned? BTW, Im using javascript regex.

For the demo please see http://jsfiddle.net/ce8Th/

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for that complex loop. Just call `replace` directly on the whole string:

```
$(this).val(function (i, v) {
    return v.replace(/%|_/g, '');
});
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ce8Th/1/

Comment: Thanks it really worked and made my code much simpler. Gonna accept this one. Just wainting for a few minutes.

Comment: I would caution that this isn't a sanitization - which might be fine for you, but it means that other characters will be allowed that may not be okay with you: spaces, tabs, random other things not in your original list.

Comment: @jakerella - The original question does not mention sanitation (though it might have been his intent - in which case *anything* client-side is useless).

Comment: @JosephSilber Good point, it wouldn't be true sanitation anyway, but just wanted to mention it in case they **did** use it as such!

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the reverse:

```
/[%_]/

if (pattern.test( ....
```

It's also nice to not use regex if you don't have to, not that it makes a big difference in this case:

```
if ("%_".split().indexOf(text.charAt(i)) > -1) {
```

Comment: I think you meant `/[^%_]/` - but you have to be careful with that, it would include a lot of other characters as well... tabs, new lines, other language characters, etc

Answer (score 2):

A white list is always best. I would recommend keeping what you have except adding a length modifier and start and end characters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$^&*()-+=]+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Would I happen to be corrent in guessing that you are using this user input for a MySQL query involving `LIKE` to search for partial matches?

If so, don't exclude characters. Instead, escape them on the server-side. For instance:

```
$output = str_replace(Array("%","_"),Array("\\%","\\_"),$input);
```

Comment: Or just `addslashes($input);`?

Comment: @jakerella `addslashes` does not consider `_` and `%` to be escapeable.